# Get all apps from Appstore by genre and country

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, app-store

I want to get all apps in a genre on a country.

i try to use :

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/genre=6018/limit=300/xml

and i get 300 apps from this category.

and i want to know if there is a way to get all apps in this genre from a country.

i tried :

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/genre=6018/limit=1500/xml

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/genre=6018/xml

and it isnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss?cc=US)

May be because 300 it is maximum value, that appstore give you.